# Knockout js - switch statement not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The following ko js switch statement is not working - if the array's length is > 0 then the statement at the end still shows.

```
<!-- ko switch -->
<!-- ko case: cards().length > 0 -->
<div id="cards-container" class="cards-container" data-bind="foreach: { data: cards }">
<div class="operator-card" data-bind="attr: {
                'data-network': networkId,
                'data-name': filters.name,
                'data-ownership': filters.ownership,
                'data-rating': filters.rating,
                'data-country': filters.country,
                'data-status': filters.status,
                'data-status-number': filters.statusnumber,
                'data-subscribers': filters.subscribers,
                'data-marketshare': filters.marketshare,
                'data-pricing-model': filters.pricingmodel,
                'data-subscriptions': filters.subscriptions,
                'data-refunds': filters.refunds
        }">
<!-- MORE CODE HERE -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko case: $else -->
        <h4>@Resources.GlobalResources.NoOperatorsFound</h4>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: You are misusing the `switch` binding. A condition should be present on switch e.g. `switch: cards().length` and based on the that value there should the case which are matching on the values e.g. is there is 0 items, 1 items, etc. In this sample you need just need a simple `if` bidning

Comment: See https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case